# ReactJs Print value instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to reactjs and trying to print update value of input field. What I firstly tried was this:

```
  var App = React.createClass({
   render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
      <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handleChange} />
      <p>{this.handleChange}</p>
    </div>;
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    return event.target.value;
  }
});
App = React.createFactory(App);

React.render(
  <App name="World" />, 
  document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

But I don't get it why it is not working. Than I tried this: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/smgjrein/pen/ozooBA) maybe someone can help me with printing instantly the value of the input field in the `<p>` element

Comment: You need to store the value of the change into state (e.g. `this.setState({ myInputValue: event.target.value });`) within your `handleChange`.  Then you can "print" the value in your `p` like so: `<p>{this.state.myInputValue}</p>`.

Comment: Highly recommend you go through the docs and tutorials. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html  Otherwise you are just guessing at the API.

Comment: Also relevant docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: @ctrlplusb yes I was looking into that, but I thought maybe there was a way to get value in handleChange event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            text: "",
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
    },
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        </div>;
    },
});
```

You must store all state of the component in `this.state`. Use `this.setState` to update the state. When you update the state, the component is automatically rerendered with the new state.

The content of the paragraph is the current value of the state. `onChange` is commonly used instead of `onKeyUp` to handle changes of state in text inputs. `handleChange` will update the state when the text input changes.